# Selenium server throws error when attempting to run test with chrome or Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-server

I have a python webdriver script which successfully runs the test on the remote server using firefox, however it throws an error when using chrome and internet explorer.

I have added the directory with both drivers to the server's path. I have also tried starting the server using: 
java -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=.\IEDriverServer.exe -role hub

I consistently get the same error in powershell:

"... - Exception: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;..."

Working Script:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.wd = webdriver.Remote(
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
```

Throws Error:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.wd = webdriver.Remote(
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

What is the culprit of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have the Selenium driver for Firefox installed and configured, but not for Chrome. Installing and configuring boils down to this ([source](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started)):

> **Setup**
>
> ChromeDriver is a separate executable that WebDriver uses to control
>   Chrome. It is maintained by the Chromium team with help from WebDriver
>   contributors. If you are unfamiliar with WebDriver, you should check
>   out their own [Getting Started page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted).
>
> Follow these steps to setup your tests for running with ChromeDriver:
>
> - **Ensure Chromium/Google Chrome is installed in a recognized location**
>     ChromeDriver expects you to have Chrome installed in the default
>     location for your platform. You can also force ChromeDriver to use a
>     custom location by setting a special capability.
> - **Download the ChromeDriver binary for your platform under the [downloads section](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) of this site**
> - **Help WebDriver find the downloaded ChromeDriver executable**
>     Any of these steps should do the trick:
>
>   - include the ChromeDriver location in your PATH environment variable
>   - (Java only) specify its location via the webdriver.chrome.driver system property (see sample below)
>   - (Python only) include the path to ChromeDriver when instantiating webdriver.Chrome (see sample below)

So, basically, you need to either set the path to your Chrome drive in the `PATH`, or instantiate the drive like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```

Comment: If this was a problem on the client side, shouldn't selenium builder be able to run the test on server at least?

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Chromedriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.15/)

```html
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org/")
```

Comment: This will run the rest on chrome local, how will it run the test on selenium server?

Comment: @BarryG did you find the solution for setting it for selenium server? can you please post the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @sridhar249 I don't remember at this point. I do remember switching to nightmare.js and using a simple testing framework like mocha, which runs the test in a dedicated electron frame which is essentially chrome. It simply was a less painful process to configure and use then selenium.

Answer (score 0):

The code is for JAVA , set the path similarly in python

If the PATH is not set in your environment variable , then set it programmatically as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path_to_your_chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```